# Manual entry of array into UiTableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

My code below is just basic tableview with nothing in it. Using a textfield and button. Textfield to place text and button to submit the text. I would like the user to only be able to enter int into the array. How can I use the textfield and button to add multiple entries to this blank tableview?

```
    import UIKit

var list = [""]

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    @IBOutlet var placeText: UITextField!



public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return(list.count)



}
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]
    return(cell)



    }

    @IBAction func enterText(_ sender: Any) {

    }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the text from the `UITextfield` to your list and reload the tableview afterwards:

```
@IBAction func enterText(_ sender: Any) {
    let newText = textfield.text
    list.append(newText)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Its saying that tableview.reloadData() has a use of unresolved identifier 'tableview'.

Comment: You have to set an `@IBOutlet` let tableView: UITableView!` from Storyboard. Also make sure you set the `delegate` and `dataSource`

Comment: Its close but what I am getting in each is just this [] no matter what a enter but at least something is being placed in the cell.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3.0**

```
@IBAction func enterText(_ sender: Any) {
    if !placeText.text!.isEmpty {
        list.append(placeText.text)
        tableview.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: I gave the validation to soon. Its saying that             tableview.reloadData() has a use of unresolved identifier 'tableview'.

Comment: Is that you set reuseIdentifier "cell" in StoryBoard tableview cell?